# Upgraded AngularJS component which requires another upgraded component can't find the parent controller when using Angular content projection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript, ng-upgrade

I am trying to do a PoC for ngUpgrade on one module of my app, and I'm running into an issue with transclusion/content projection along with AngularJS `requires`.

Let's say there's a downgraded Angular component defined like:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'common-filter',
  template: `
    <ajs-filter>
      <div>Common Filter</div>
      <ajs-button text="Outside of content projection"></ajs-button>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </ajs-filter>
})

export class CommonFilter {}
```

`ajsButton` is an upgraded AngularJS component that requires a parent controller:

```
require: {
  ajsFilterCtrl: '^ajsFilter'
}
```

A normal use of `common-filter` works perfectly fine, however when projecting an `ajs-button` like:

```
<common-filter>
  <ajs-button text="Inside of content projection"></ajs-button>
</common-filter>
```

This error is thrown:

`Unhandled Promise rejection: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'ajsFilter', required by directive 'ajsButton', can't be found!`

Is there any way around this? I know that I can rewrite the surrounding classes, but many other apps use them and I need to be able to upgrade the apps gradually.

**Working Example:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngupgradestatic-playground-uvr14t

Snippets above are from `index.html` and `common-filter.component.ts`. This is a (more-or-less) minimal example based on much more complicated components. I'm going with the `downgradeModule` approach for performance reasons.

Comment: I'm not sure how else to communicate this, but for other prospective editors of my question -- please research what ngUpgrade is before suggesting incorrect edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A maintainer, gkalpak, provided a workaround for this issue in the Github issue that I posted for this:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24846#issuecomment-404448494

In short, this is an issue with the order of initialization of the different controllers.
To get around it, you can make the parent `require` optional and then use `setTimeout` to wait until the parent controller is initialized:

```
this.$onInit = () => {
  this.requireAjsFilterCtrl().then(() => console.log('!', !!this.ajsFilterCtrl));
}

this.requireAjsFilterCtrl = () => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.ajsFilterCtrl = this.ajsFilterCtrl || $element.controller('ajsFilter');
      resolve(this.ajsFilterCtrl);
    });
  });
};
```

The workaround can be seen in action here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngupgradestatic-playground-a6zkwb